# Подскажите что за файл config.ru в Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Подскажите что за файл `config.ru` и для чего он служит?
Внутри такой код

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы переведёте ответ на ваш вопрос с английской версии сайта и добавите его здесь

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю файла с расширением `.ru`. Ну, даже если и `.ru`, то очевидно, что это что-то рубиноидное.

```
require './app' # Подключение приложения
run Sinatra::Application # Запуск
```

Comment: А зачем отвечаете, если не знаете?

Comment: @Василиса, я что, неправильный ответ дал?

Comment: Если бы он был правильный, то было бы хоть слово про Rack

Comment: @Василиса, а где ваш ответ? Мало ли чего в нем нет.